# C# find numbers between two dots?

Tags: c#, .net

So, basically what i need is to get numbers that are between second and third dot.

Example:
I type in my textbox "1.1.1.1" or "183.312.21.132", I click a button and in the seconds textbox I get numbers that are between second and third dot. Like for first one it would be "1" and for seconds one it will be "21"

Sorry for bad English. Thanks!

Comment: If you have three or more dots, all the answers given will solve your problem. Since you said that the length of the data is unknown, what would be the required outputs if you have like "2", "4.5", "3.4.2" & "2.5.7.1.6.8"?

Answer (score 4):

try split

```
"1.1.1.1".Split('.')[2]
```

or

```
"183.312.21.132".Split('.')[2]
```

returns a string[] and index 2 would be the third number

Comment: works perfectly as per what you wanted in your question, would you like to please rephrase your question then

Answer (score 3):

Use string split:

```
"183.312.21.132".Split(".")[index_of_the_dot_before_desired_numbers]
```

i.e.

```
"183.312.21.132".Split('.')[2] = "21"
```

UPD:

if you need a range between dots, you can use LINQ:

```
var startDotIndex=1; 
var endDotIndex=3;
"183.312.21.132".Split('.').Skip(startDotIndex).Take(endDotIndex-startDotIndex).ToArray()
```

will return ["312", "21"];

Answer (score 2):

```
string digits[] = "1.2.3.4".Split(".");
```

Use elsewhere with:

```
digits[0]
digits[1]
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how many digits each part is, as long as you know that you want first, second, third part. digits[2] will return 3 for 1.2.3.4, and 144 for 192.168.144.1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the String object's Split method see below:

```
string foo = "183.312.21.132";
string[] foos = foo.Split('.');
```

from here you can do many different things such as loop through your array and grab values or if you know exactly what index you are looking for you can simply request it straight from the array such as:

```
string bar = foo.Split('.')[2]; // gives you "21"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = "192.168.0.1";
var digs = foo.Split(".");
var nums = int.Parse(digs[2]);
```